# "Capable" Vs "Able"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Imagine you are describing someone who has lots of abilities in a field (for example, a scientist who knows a lot about a specific topic and has had done lots of researches in that respect and has written a lot of articles in that regard).

He can do any project related to that topic.

Which one of the following sentences works better:

> - He is very **capable** in this field.
> - He is **able** in this field.

As far as I know, the latter one should be a more precise example, because the scientist in the question can do anything right now and he has proved it prior to this.

Comment: The first example is idiomatic; the second is not. Stick with "capable" in this instance.

Comment: I'd say [***competent***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capable+in+mathematics%2Ccompetent+in+mathematics&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapable%20in%20mathematics%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompetent%20in%20mathematics%3B%2Cc0) is far more idiomatic for your context (and ***able*** is very unlikely).

Comment: If using ***competent*** as suggested by @FumbleFingers, you can use adverbs such as [***highly***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/highly) or [***extremely***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extremely) in the place of ***very*** to signify higher competence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He is very **capable** in this field.

This is a very normal way of expressing what you intend, as is "competent"  as pointed out by FumbleFingers.  The *able* version of the sentence does not work for this context.  "Able" is more often used to mean that someone is not prohibited or restricted from doing something - not that they are good at it.

Answer (score 2):

capable = competent
He is very ***capable*** in his field.

means he can do things in his area of expertise better than most.

You could also say

[image]
<sub>(source: [sharonwords.co.il](http://sharonwords.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D.jpg))</sub>

>He is **outstanding** in his field.

(sorry, I couldn't resist)